# sandcastle, how to link to non-framework classes in msdn?

Tags: .net, sandcastle

When I create a website with Sandcastle it's not linking other non-framework classes from Microsoft, like ASP.NET MVC or Unity.

Comment: @Daniel A. White: The links (to MSDN) to non-framework types from Microsoft are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer from Eric Woodruff [here](http://shfb.codeplex.com/discussions/288058):

> You may be able to get it to resolve the links by adding the
>   Additional Reference Links plug-in to your main project which
>   effectively does the above.  Create a separate project for the MVC and
>   Unity assemblies and add them to it, then add that project to the
>   plug-in configuration with the appropriate link type properties set to
>   MSDN in the plug-in item configuration.  If the MSDN web service knows
>   about the MVC and Unity types, it should then resolve them.